# Convert Xamarin.Forms measure units to pixels

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I convert, for example, `view.WidthRequest` value to platform pixels? I'm looking for method like `Device.ConvertToPixels(10)`.

I want to use it for SkiaSharp drawing. For example I want to draw circle with stroke = 10 in (xamarin.forms units) which will be converted to pixels on draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply MainDisplayInfo.Density by (xamarin.forms units) and you get that pixels.

I made a method.

```
    double XamDIUConvertToPixels(double XamDIU)
    {
        var desplayinfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        var pixcels = desplayinfo.Density * XamDIU;
        return pixcels;
    }
```

DeviceDisplay must be done on the UI thread or else an exception will be thrown in iOS.

read this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?tabs=ios#platform-differences

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a scale at the top of the draw and then use whatever units you like.

For example, on a 2x display, you can do a `canvas.Scale(2)` and then draw as if it was a 1x.

In the case of a Xamarin.Forms paint event, there is the event args that has all the info you need:

```cs
canvas.Scale(e.Info.Width / view.Width);
```

Also, you can have a look at this blog post where I show off some things: https://dotnetdevaddict.co.za/2020/01/12/who-cares-about-the-view-anyway/

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below:

In Android:

```
var dp = 100;
        int pixel = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, dp, this.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
```

In Xamarin.Forms, try to use the Dependency Service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: What about iOS?

Comment: For ios, there is no need to convert. The format of the value you get is pixel.