# How can I get the correct pixel on an image/bitmap from a point of touch in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, touch-event, color-picker

I am trying to get the location of touch from image on screen and map it to the correlating pixel from stream in order to determine the color (like a color picker).
But I realise the issue is the points gotten from the touch are mere small values which are just about matching the upper left corner of the actual image.

```
   void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
        {
            // Get touchpoint location

            Point pt = new Point();
            pt.X = args.Location.X;
            pt.Y = args.Location.Y;

            GetColor();
        }
```

I have simply called the GetPixel() function on the skbitmap image with x, and y from above location.
I have also tried resizing the image from stream to the canvasview but with no luck. please help?

Comment: there is an entire page of [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/pixels) that discusses Skia coordinates vs XF coordinates

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63612367/199364 may be helpful. The essential point is that XF coords are in "Device-Independent Units" (DIUs), Skia is in pixels. The relationship between those two is: `nPixels = Density * nDIUs;` or the other direction: `nDIUs = nPixels / Density;` See link for how to get `Density`.